# Is there a third-party business card designer widget for a website?

Tags: asp.net, flash

I am a part-time IT worker for a university print shop. Over the years my predecessor and I have created a very simple, custom ASP.NET website to allow employees to submit print orders, which we then process and deliver.

We have long allowed employees to order business cards, but we only let them enter a few fields - their name, phone number, fax number, etc. - which we then print out on a common stock. But my boss would now like to offer employees more customization, from uploading a photo of themselves to include on the business card, to adding an optional message at the bottom of the card which the employee could customize by entering the text, the font, the color, and so on.

This is a bit beyond my skillset. Are there any out of the box third-party products we could buy (or that may be freeware) that would provide a rich design experience? Ideally the customer would have a rich canvas like with Vistaprint.com or any other sort of commercial, direct to consumer, online business card company.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why not get in touch with the computer engineering department?  One of my biggest gripes about my college experience was never getting any hands-on experience (that is, until senior-year when they threw us into a real-world project using Java and a few other languages that we were never taught.)  This project is not difficult at all, and I suspect that they could get it done in about a month's time.

They should be able to produce something that not only allows the user to use a custom image, but they could also allow users to move the Name, Address, etc. anywhere on the card, etc.

Comment: Before I was hired here they went down that path (or tried to), but had no luck. The computer science department does not have any classes on Microsoft technologies, and we are using ASP.NET. So we cannot get any professor support, and we have no budget to hire a student.